# Cannot execute Bash script in Ubuntu with Parllel Desktop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, parallels

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 Using Parallels Desktop 17.

I recently had to update Parallels from version 15 (as well as parallels tools) and after the update i encounter an error when executing bash scripts:

/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Invalid argument

Does anyone know why this is or what i can do to investigate the problem?

I have tried reinstalling Parallels Tools as well as bash. And i have also tried to run a few different bash scripts (which all worked before) to make sure it wasn't the script itself.

Info:

Bash-version: version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Parallels Desktop: 17.0.0

Parallels Tools: Unknown, but updated after PD was updated.

Oh, and of course i tried to google this beforehand, but all i found was examples of people having trouble with bad interpreter: no such file or directory, or people having trouble with windows/linux line endings, neither of which seems to be the case for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i updated the parallels tools, but with Parallels 16.  This issue started after update of parallels tools, but there was no way to rollback to an older version of it.

I uninstalled Parallels tools (within ubuntu) and then Updating Parallels to 17, it automatically installed parallels tools and now everything is fine again.

As you already have Parallels 17, i am not sure if this will help you.

Comment: This should not be an answer, but it could be a comment asking for more details.